# How do I print a list choosen by the user via input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables

I have two lists defined in a python program, I'm getting user input via the `input("...")` function.

The user is supposed to input a list name so I can print it to the console, the problem is that I can only print the list name and not the actual list itself.

Here are my lists:

```
aaa = [1,2,3,4,5]
bbb = [6,7,8,9,10]
```

Here is the code I'm using the get the user input:

```
a = input("Input list name")
```

Here is the code I'm using to print the list:

```
print(a)
```

Here is the expected output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Instead this is the output I'm getting:

```
aaa
```

Answer (score 2):

Your input is `str` and you are trying to print string not a list when you do `print(a)`.

You need to understand `str` and variable name are not the same thing.

`aaa` is not same as `'aaa'`

You can use `dict` in this case

```
# store your lists in dict as below
d = {'aaa': [1,2,3,4,5], 'bbb':[6,7,8,9,10]}

a=input('Input list name: ')

# this will handle if user input does not match to any key in dict
try:
    print(d[a])
except:
    print("Please enter correct name for list")
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#locals) function, like this:

```
aaa = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
bbb = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
target = input("What list would you like to see? ")
# NOTE: please don't (I REPEAT DON'T) use eval here
#     : it WILL cause security flaws
#     : try to avoid eval as much as possible
if target in locals():
  found = locals()[target]
  # basic type checking if you only want the user to be able to print lists
  if type(found) == list:
    print(found)
  else:
    print("Whoops! You've selected a value that isn't a list!")
else:
  print("Oh no! The list doesn't exist")
```

Here is a more concise version of the same code:

```
aaa = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
bbb = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

target = input("Enter list name: ")

if target in locals():
  found = locals()[target]
  print(found if type(found) == list else "Value is not a list.")
else:
  print("Target list doesn't exist")
```

**NOTE:** in the second answer the code is smaller because I've removed comments, used smaller messages and added a ternary operator.

**NOTE:** view [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/10415695) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/10415695) to find out more about why using [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#eval) is bad.

Good luck.